# What should I pass to handleRequest class of symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am using this twig and standalone symfony form and validator component:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
// other use lines ommitted to shorten the code.

$defaultFormTheme = 'bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig';

$csrfGenerator = new UriSafeTokenGenerator();
$csrfStorage = new NativeSessionTokenStorage();
$csrfManager = new CsrfTokenManager($csrfGenerator, $csrfStorage);

$formEngine = new TwigRendererEngine([$defaultFormTheme], $twig);
$twig->addRuntimeLoader(new FactoryRuntimeLoader([
    FormRenderer::class => function () use ($formEngine, $csrfManager) {
        return new FormRenderer($formEngine, $csrfManager);
    },
]));
$twig->addExtension(new FormExtension());

$translator = new Translator('fr_FR');
$translator->addLoader('php', new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\PhpFileLoader());
$translator->addResource('php', ROOT.'/translations/messages.fr.php', 'fr_FR');
$twig->addExtension(new TranslationExtension($translator));

$validator = Validation::createValidator();

$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    ->addExtension(new CsrfExtension($csrfManager))
    ->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))
    ->getFormFactory();

$form = $formFactory->createBuilder(FormType::class, null, ['csrf_protection' => false])
    ->add('firstnameEn', TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => [new Assert\Length(['min' => 3])]
        ])
    ->add('lastnameEn', TextType::class)
    ->add('email', EmailType::class)
    ->add('birthDate', TextType::class)
    ->add('password', PasswordType::class)
    ->add('applyCard', CheckboxType::class)
    ->add('showPhoto', CheckboxType::class)
    ->add('privacyRead', CheckboxType::class)
    ->getForm();

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

   $errors = $form->getErrors();
   var_dump($errors);
   $data = $form->getErrors();
   var_dump($data);
   print("debug pring");

} else {

   $errors = $form->getErrors();
   var_dump($errors);
   $data = $form->getErrors();
   var_dump($data);
   print("debug pring");

}

echo $twig->render('signup.html', 
['form' => $form->createView(),
 'title' => 'title',
]);
```

I am getting

```
Expected argument of type "null", "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request" given
```

that is because of

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Why am I getting this error and how to fix it? when I use just

```
$form->handleRequest();
```

it works, but of course then form validation is not working. How to fix it? What should I pass to its constructor? I I didn't want to use its isSubmitted() if clause and had no need to validate it and I wanted to use just to output the form it was working fine. The problem appeared when I wanted to use HTTFoundation to use isSubmitted if clause. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Form component uses request handlers ([symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#request-handling)) to handle requests in the `handleRequest()` method. From the linked documentation:

> To process form data, you'll need to call the [`handleRequest()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php) method:
>
> ```php
> $form->handleRequest();
> ```
>
> Behind the scenes, this uses a [`NativeRequestHandler`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/src/Symfony/Component/Form/NativeRequestHandler.php) object to read data off of the correct PHP superglobals (i.e. `$_POST` or `$_GET`) based on the HTTP method configured on the form (POST is default).

If you want to use the `Request` object from the HttpFoundation, you might want to configure the Form component to us the [`HttpFoundationRequestHandler`](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php) instead. In that case, you have to pass the `$request` argument to the `handleRequest()` method.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks. I know how to translate fieldnames with Symfony Translator, but how to translate constraint error messages too? @Wouter J

Comment: @user4271704 search if the question isn't yet answered on this site and otherwise create a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58366138/how-to-translate-symfony-form-error-messages/58367600#58367600